# Enabling flags (Wall, pedantic) for C/C++ compilation within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compilation, compiler-flags

I am using Eclipse to write C/C++ programs. I would like to compile my code using the -Wall and -pedantic flags. How do I enable these flags within Eclipse so they are used by default whenever I compile a C/C++ program?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> your project -> context menu -> Properties.

A dialog appears. In the left pane, open "C/C++ Build" -> Settings. In the right pane, ensure that tab "Tool Settings" is selected -> Under "GCC C++ Compiler" select "Warnings" -> check the boxes that you want.

In your case, you want "Pedantic (-pedantic)". "All warnings (-Wall)" should already be checked by default. You may want "Extra warnings (-Wextra)" (alias "-W"), too.